# How to disable shift delete on my system totally even through remote control

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I trying to disable my SHIFT+DELETE option on my laptop.For that, I found an answer to use the script(below) in AutoHotkey program to prevent SHIFT+DELETE. It is working perfectly when I am doing locally, But this is not working while accessing through remote control.

```
+Del::
KeyWait Shift
Send {Delete}
return
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029). Why do you want to disable `Shift`+`Del`?

Comment: I am giving access to my computer to someone remotely.So for my need, I just want to explore options.

Comment: You haven't actually answered my question, I still don't know what problem you're trying to solve and I have to guess. If you want to prevent people from permanently deleting files, then disabling `Shift`+`Del` is not sufficient, one can alternatively right-click a file and click `Delete` while holding `Shift` (so you'd have to disable `Shift` entirely, which is not an acceptable solution I suppose).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10: how to protect myself from accidentally deleting a specific folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1480892/windows-10-how-to-protect-myself-from-accidentally-deleting-a-specific-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
+Del::return ; do nothing
```

or

```
Shift & Del::return
```

or

```
#If GetKeyState("Shift","P")

    Del::return

#If
```

Comment: How can I bypass SHIFT+DELETE file to some specific location

Comment: You can make this hotkey definition context-sensitive by using the [#If](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) or the [#IfWinExist/#IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive.