# Windows 10: how to protect myself from accidentally deleting a specific folder

Tags: windows-10, files-folders

I have a 'WORK' folder with client files and making constant changes to its subfolders 'CLIENTXX' and files within. However, i have a tendency to SHIFT+DELETE (permanently delete) stuff instead of sending to the Bin, so the dilemma is how do i *lock* the WORK folder so i can *never* delete it, but still be able to have full access to its subfolders and files?

I have tried making stuff 'Read only' but that's not much help as i keep editing files in these client subfolders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplished with a little work.

- Right click the folder you want to prevent deletion and select `Properties`.
- While on the `Security` tab, click the `Advanced` button.
- Select your user in `Permissions` tab dialog.
- Select the `Disable Inheritance`
- Then select `Convert Inherited Permissions...`
- Then double-click your user name
- Click `Show advanced permissions` on the right side
- Uncheck `Delete` and click `OK` then `Apply`

You can no longer delete those files, but you can still modify them.  Obviously, if these files are important, you should be making backups.

Comment: It may be easier to just add an access entry that will explicitly deny deletion, which works with inheritable permissions. (Either way, I'd expect the folder to quickly fill up with MS Office temporary files which it can no longer delete...)

Comment: There is already a Google Drive live sync in place for the WORK folder, so there is backup, but just wanted to somehow disable deletion.